# Wso2 IS 5.2.0 : Openid connect role claim

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

1. I have following claim configuration in SP (note     http://wso2.org/claims/role has been added)
   [image]
2. role claim in http://wso2.org/claims dialect as follows
   [image]
3. Now I have added the mapping "Role" claim to http://wso2.org/oidc/claim dialect which has same Mapped Attribute (role)

[image]

4. Then added the "roles" claim uri to the openid scope defined in registry at /_system/config/oidc
   [image]

But still I can not get any roles by accessing userinfo EP.

curl -k -H "Authorization: Bearer 7f5b531c-f1d9-3775-8de8-30acf09e8673" https://localhost:9443/oauth2/userinfo?schema=openid

returns 
{"sub":"admin@carbon.super","name":"admin","family_name":"admine","email":"adminvvvvvv@wso2.com"}

Can anybody point out if I missed anything?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing to tick "**support by default**" option in **step-03**. You can find more details here [1].

[1] http://workaroundz.blogspot.com/2016/10/define-custom-claims-for-openid-connect.html

Comment: worked for me, but noticed if empty space there in value of property in oidc configuration it does not work..